# Hide a label based on selection of UISegmented controls at run time

Tags: swift, uisegmentedcontrol

I have two segments in UISegmented Controls. What I want is to hide a label based upon selection of segment at run time.

For e.g:

```
if SegControl.selectedSegmentIndex == 1 {
    descriptStar.isHidden = true
    PriceStar.isHidden = true                               
}
```

I am trying this but it is not working. Please help.

Thanks

Comment: Do neither of them hide?

Comment: what exactly the problem is?

Comment: They are not getting hidden based upon selection by segmented controls. I selected second segment i.e with index 1 and it is supposed to hide but it doesn't hide.

Comment: Make sure you are binding the `valueChange` method to the segment control and doing your code in that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I previously had an outlet from segmentedControl but not an `@IBAction` method. I created an `@IBAction` method connected to the segmented control and inserted the code to hide labels in that function and it worked.